# Passing polymorphic objects between processes

Tags: c++, windows, process, ipc

I'm trying to understand different kinds of C++ Windows IPC mechanisms and I have always the same question, creating a mess in my head - **how do I send and receive objects of my custom classes between processes?** 
I have already done client/server programs that were sending and receiving null terminated strings but I have never sent a real object nor touched the de/serialization.

I also know that it is impossible to successfully send a pointer to a polymorphic object, but **is it possible to send an object of class derived from abstract class that is dynamically casted to it's true type?**

And the third question is - if the answer to the second question is yes - **how do I define what type of object is about to come?** I have imagined I can just send the fixed size information about incoming object and then send the object.

I feel a bit lost in this topic, if you have any beginner friendly source of information about different C++ Windows IPC mechanisms I would be very thankful to read these. :)

Comment: There are many choices, but the most commonly used one is COM. COM uses pass-by-reference by default, which means that the thing passed between processes is not the object itself, but a reference to the object. What passes between the process is an interface. This is a large topic, too big for an SO answer.

Comment: Yes it is a vast topic, but i forgot to mention that i actually look for something very efficient like shared memory. From what I have heard the COM is relatively slow.

Comment: You are welcome to use shared memory if you wish.